# Android Gradle Sync error

Tags: android, gradle

Here is the problem that I get when trying to preform a Gradle sync, I am also running the latest android studio and have included the minifyEnabled

```
 Error:(33, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'MLGSoundboard' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Comment: Try minifyEnabled() in place of runProguard() and see if it works. If not, check your plugins and install them.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an issue with the project's gradle configuration. Just make a new project, and drag over everything except for the gradle files from the old project to the new one.